# PyUnicode_FromString is thread safe?

Tags: python, c++

I am using [`PyUnicode_FromString()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_FromString) and [`PyUnicode_AsUTF8()`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/unicode.html#c.PyUnicode_AsUTF8) while doing python extension from CPP,  which is crashing when we use more than one thread .
Is `PyUnicode_FromString()` and `PyUnicode_AsUTF8()` thread safe ?

```
predictGplaceBoxClockregion(int iterationNo,
                            std::string y_value,
                            std::string gplaceFeatureFile,
                            int levelNo,
                            bool analytical)
{
  std::string result = "";
  PyObject *d = PyDict_New();

  if (iterationNo == 1) {
      y_value = "ClockRegion_MultiLabel_iter1";
  } else {
      y_value = "ClockRegion_MultiLabel_iter2";
  }

  PyDict_SetItemString(d, "ip", PyUnicode_FromString(gplaceFeatureFile.c_str()));
  PyDict_SetItemString(d, "y", PyUnicode_FromString(y_value.c_str()));
  PyDict_SetItem(d, PyUnicode_FromString("iterNo"), PyLong_FromLong(iterationNo));
  PyObject *methodcall = PyObject_CallMethod(instance, "bindScript", "O", d);
  if ( methodcall == nullptr) {
        PyErr_Print();
  }
  result     = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(methodcall);
  Py_DECREF (d);

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you show failing code?

Comment: shared the code

Comment: Are you ensuring the GIL state?

Comment: About threading, (global) `instance` access seems problematic.